# JSF - base page refresh automatically after close popup window

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I have three pages

1. main page
2. popup page started from main page using onclick javascript method (consists only input and button)
3. *foo* page

I'm creating form on main page, for some operations is admin key needed, so popup window is opened by button. When popup window is filled, submitted and key is found in database, popup window is redirected to *foo* page and it is closed. So I'm back on main page and I need it automatically refresh to take the changes.

I can't do it using by `onclick="window.opener.location.href='main.xhtml';` on button because its too quick a there is time delay to find key in database.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you close it? Are you injecting JavaScript after the postback?

Add a function that refreshes the opener;

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.opener.reload(true);
};
window.close();
```

Untested.

BalusC is probably right in his comment, it would be sufficient with

```
window.opener.reload(true);
window.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm redirecting it to foo.xhtml which is closed by <script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>

Comment: The `onunload` is unnecessary (and also not supported in some browsers). Just `<script>window.opener.reload(true); window.close();</script>` ought to be sufficient.

Comment: But who is window.opener if I closing popup page by redirecting to foo.xhtml?

Comment: @gaffcz - it should still be the same window. The opener only changes/disappears when you reload or navigate away in the top page (the opener).

Comment: I have main page, popup page and foo page. Foo page is closed using window.close(). I think opener is popup page now but it doesn't exists because it has been redirected. The result is, the popup window is refreshed but there is nothing, is white :)

Comment: Related to @BalusC comment. The code is not working for me. I have to use `window.opener.location.reload(true);window.close();`. Just for the record, but it was helping me anyway, so thanks!